# Roots of $ax^2+bx+1 = 0$ are given, then find roots of $x^2+(b^3-3ab)x + a^3 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

Roots of $ax^2+bx+1 = 0$ are given as $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt\alpha}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt\beta}$.
Find roots of $x^2+(b^3-3ab)x + a^3 = 0$

**Method 1:**

I assumed $(\alpha)^{-1/2} =x$ and the new variable in which we form the new quadratic as $X$ whose root is $\alpha '$. Then

$$\alpha^{-n/2} = \alpha '\\
\implies x = X^{1/n}$$

Substituting $x$ in first quadratic,

$$aX^{2/n}+bX^{1/n}=-1$$

On cubing

$$a^3X^{6/n}+b^3X^{3/n}+3abX^{3/n}(aX^{2/n}+bX^{1/n}) = -1$$

Substituting $aX^{2/n}+bX^{1/n}=-1$, we get:

$$a^3X^{6/n}+b^3X^{3/n}-3abX^{3/n} = -1$$

Comparing with second quadratic, we get $n=-3$. Thus 
$$\alpha ' = \alpha^{3/2}$$

**Method 2:**

I try using sum and product of root formulas:

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt\alpha} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt\beta} = -\dfrac{b}{a}\\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt\alpha\sqrt\beta} = \dfrac{1}{a}$$

So we get $$\sqrt\alpha + \sqrt \beta = -b$$

So product of roots of neq quadratic is $$\alpha ' \beta ' = a^3  = (\alpha \beta) ^ {3/2}$$

And sum of new roots is 
$$\begin{align}
\alpha ' + \beta ' = 3ab-b^3 &= b(3a-b^2) \\
&= (\sqrt\alpha + \sqrt \beta)((\sqrt \alpha + \sqrt \beta)^2 - 3\sqrt{\alpha\beta} ) \\
&= (\alpha^{3/2} + \beta ^{3/2})
\end{align}$$

Thus comparing gives the same answer.

My question is also that which approach is more proper and **general**. Also is there an **easier** approach for this?

Comment: The second method is probably the easier method of solving this problem.

Comment: I thought of using the second method too as I've seen the question, I think the first one is long and troubling, there is a lot of chance for you to make mistakes whereas the second one is safer and quicker, however the first method might be more suitable in some proofs and rather special questions.

Comment: The second method is clearer, especially if you know the identity $u^3+v^3=(u+v)^3-3uv(u+v)$, used in the derivation of the solution of cubic equations.